# How do you get Windows 11 not to sleep when closing lid

Tags: windows, sleep-mode

I previously had my laptop set to not go to sleep when I close the lid but I can't find the setting anymore. I found the power & battery page but I no longer see the setting for what to do when the lid is closed. Does anyone know if this is still possible?

[image]

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming-related questions.